# table value is not updated using update statement

Tags: iphone

i need to update a column value into table.

for that my code is,

```
NSString *sql_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update %@ Set Quantiry = %@ Where ItemName = %@", tableName,quantity,itemname];
    const char *sqlStatement = (char *)[sql_str UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"query %s",sqlStatement);
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);

    sqlite3_close(database);
```

displayed query in console is `update allcategories Set Quantiry = 11 Where ItemName = Bananas`

but the value in table is not updated.

what the wrong,can any one please help me.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing one line after sqlite3_prepare_v2. you have to use sqlite3_step() after this. use following:

```
NSString *sql_str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"update %@ Set Quantiry = %@ Where ItemName = %@", tableName,quantity,itemname];
const char *sqlStatement = (char *)[sql_str UTF8String];
NSLog(@"query %s",sqlStatement);
sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
sqlite3_step(compiledStatement);
}

sqlite3_close(database);
```

hope helps.. :)